# How to make image fill entire stage/container in galleria

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, galleria

For some reason, my images aren't filling the entire stage in galleria. Here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

The dimensions of the image are being computed, but I don't know where from:

```
<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1" width="434" style="display: block; opacity: 1; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; max-width: none; max-height: none; width: 434px; height: 290px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 83px;" height="290">
```

I'd like the images to fill the entire stage.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try setting the imageCrop option to true:

```
Galleria.run('#galleria', {
    imageCrop: true,
});
```

Comment: I also had to add to remove the 60px bottom margin.  I am using the default theme (v1.4.7)<br> `.galleria-theme-classic .galleria-stage
 {
  bottom:0px;  /* removed default 60px */
}